# Star Schema - Fact table without uniqueness

Tags: ssas, database-schema

We have a data warehouse that contains a large fact table with over 100 million rows.  I'm trying to create a cube that includes this fact table and need to create a fact dimension based off of this table.  The issue that I'm running into is that there is no way to find uniqueness on this table using the fields that would be included in the fact dimension, without using every field in the table.

I created a surrogate key in the dsv using:

```
Row_Number() OVER (ORDER BY ID, Dt, Num)
```

I've used this method to create a surrogate key in another dsv and it worked, but I was also able to find uniqueness with the fields in the Order By.

When I browse the cube based on this fact table I get the correct results when using regular dimensions.  When I try to use fields from fact dimension I get eroneous results in most cases...some are correct, though very few.

Would this be a case where I should request that a surrogate key get created on the fact table?  Is there a better solution that someone could suggest?

Comment: Are you sure you want to create a fact dimension (aka a degenerated dimension)?

I don't see the business value to create a fact dimension in this case if you have no unique key on your fact table.

Comment: There are many fields in the fact table that i want/need to make available.

Comment: Yes but can't you create normal dimensions with these fields? I think that you're over-abusing the concept of a fact dimension. A fact dimension should be used only if the cardinality of the dimension is identical to the number of facts. If you can't create a Unique Key on your fact, you won't have the same granularity in your fact and in your dimension. Could you provide an abstract of the table's content to illustrate your problem?

Comment: That's why I was asking if it would make sense to add a unique key to the table itself. It would need to be justified to the DW team, since it would be adding an integer to 100+ million rows.  What I was trying to do was to add the key in the dsv.           The table is a combination of 8 foriegn keys, ~15 measures and ~35 additional fields (including several dates).

Comment: Well, a clean solution would be to move the 35 fields to their own dimension(s), and only have foreign keys and measures in the fact table. As an intermediate step, you could have a key numbering the unique combinations of those of the 35 fields that you need, and then use that as a foreign key to a dimension view which would just be these fields and the unique key built from the table using `group by`.

Comment: Vased on your previous responses, in this case, you should create standard dimension(s) in place of a fact dimension. For this you will probably need to review your data model having a fact table with 35 additional fields to define dimensions is not a good idea.